# (Swing) cannot find symbol of setText

Tags: java, swing

I'm having this issue with Swing `setText`: **error: cannot find symbol**

I've done the following steps, with instructions from the same ticket posted before, but no help:

- Uncheck Save on Compile option of the project
- Clean and build
- Delete cache in \AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0.2\index

My code simply gets a value from the NetBean inbuilt DB and displays it in a text field:

```
public void doConnect(){
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
    String name = "root";
    String pass = "123";
    try{
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, name, pass);
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    String SQL = "select * from ROOT.WORKERS";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

    rs.next();
    String fname = rs.getString("FIRST_NAME");
    String lname = rs.getString("LAST_NAME");

    firstname = setText(fname);
    lastname = setText(lname);

    }
    catch(SQLException err)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers4.this, err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: A out of context snippet of code doesn't help.  What does your object extend from?  What is `setText` suppose to do? What are you trying to achieve with the code?

Comment: The below answer works for me. Thanks for answering!

Comment: You were lucky that same one could "guess" your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just write `setText` without calling it on an object or writing the method in that class. In this case, you should be calling it on a text field object. If `firstname` and `lastname` are your text fields, write it like this.

```
firstname.setText(fname);
lastname.setText(lname);
```